# HP EliteBook 8xxx Notebooks compatiblity 2Q

Tags: bluetooth, hp-elitebook, windows-hello

Are HP EliteBook 8xxx Notebooks compatible with:

1- Smart Blue tooth
 2- Windows Hello

Comment: Have you checked HP website or the manuals they have on site?

Comment: @mic84: Yes, I did. Nothing there as this is a pretty old model. they do not have even drivers for windows 10.